# Cannot send message to user in discord.py with their id

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I got a question. I am making a mod-mail bot working with the id's of the user. But when I use the id I get the following error:

`raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`

This is weird because after research I found this was the best way to do this. The goal is to send the message to the user. And I checked, the mistake is not within the `user_id` part because this is the correct id. What do I need to do to fix this?

This command is just to test. This is not the actual command

Here is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def id(ctx):
    # take the id of the user it needs to send the message to
    channel_name = ctx.channel.name
    user_id = channel_name
    # declare the member it needs to send it to
    member = bot.get_user(user_id)

    # printing some things so I can check what It returns
    print (user_id)
    print (member)
    print('------')

    # send the message to the user
    await member.send("Confirmed")
```

Comment: Why are you making it so complicated? `ctx, member: discord.Member` and then `member.send` makes it much easier... A `NoneType` error means that the user does not exist/the bot maybe can't see the member.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I want it to be possible without. Since the mods in my server don't have developer mode on.

Comment: `discord.Member` = `@Mention / Name / ID` are possible...

Comment: Yeah that is true. But they cannot mention the name because the user does not have access to the channel. In your previous comment you mentioned the bot not being able to see the channel or the user not existing. But I checked and the id is correct and the bot can see the channel. Are there any other reasons that can cause this?

Comment: Your problem is not quite clear here either. You want to create a modmail bot and then a person can create a channel via a command or how do you imagine that? How should the message be sent, when and or why?

Comment: So when the user dm's the bot. It will create a private channel wish only the mods can enter. The mods can use a command `reply` and reply to the user. Now the command is `reply [user] [msg]` but since I like to make it easier for them I thought of `reply [msg]`. So now when you dm the bot it will create a private channel with your id as the name. When the mods use the reply command it will grab the id and send the message. This way the mods and users can communicate trough the bot. But this is where the error comes in. It cannot send the message because of the error mentioned In the original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_id` is a string, it should be an integer

```py
@bot.command()
async def id(ctx):
    # take the id of the user it needs to send the message to
    channel_name = ctx.channel.name
    user_id = int(channel_name)

    member = bot.get_user(user_id)

    print(user_id)
    print(member)

    await member.send("Confirmed")
```

Comment: Hmmm, when I added this I still got the same error

Comment: That's weird, have you enabled member intents?

Comment: Oh that must be the problem. I don't think I have. Where can I do this?

Comment: In the developers portal: https://discord.com/developers/applications, you also need to enable them in your code ([guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html))

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Thanks for all your help today, also the one on my older questions

Comment: Happy to help:)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `bot.get_user()` fails to retrieve the `Member` because your passing it a `str` representation of the actual ID.

Cast the user_id before passing it to the function: `bot.get_user(int(user_id))`

However, why are you doing all this instead of just extracting the member from `ctx`?

Comment: How do I member intents? I have never heard of this

Comment: Actually I've edited my answer, it seems you didn't find the member object because you passed a string version of the member ID

Comment: Oh i searched the docs. I found it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that you try to invoke the `send` method of a nonexisting object, which is denoted by `NoneType`. As a general approach, you need to check where send is being invoked. From your code I can find a single example:

```
await member.send("Confirmed")
```

As a result, `member` is of `NoneType`. This is how `member` is being defined

```
member = bot.get_user(user_id)
```

and since you have clearly stated that `user_id` is correct, what logically follows is that `bot.get_user` will not yield the user identified by a correct `user_id`. `user_id` is the channel name, which sounds weird, since a channel is usually a different thing from a user.

In order to figure out you will need to debug `get_user` if possible. Pass a correct `user_id` there and see whether it's found. You should be able to reproduce the problem with the exact scenario you test with. It's possible that the channel name is of different type from the stored `user_id` values. See whether you are able to get the proper user by id. If you are able to do so, then it should work in a real scenario as well.